# if possible to align arrow by image HTML/CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have a carousel with some images and titles:

```
    <div class="photo-carousel">

        <div class="carousel-arrow">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <i class="arrow-left"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <ul class="photo-list">
            <li class="photo">
                <div class="image-wrap">...</div>

                <div class="title">....</div>

                <div class="description">...</div>
            </li>

            <li class="photo">
                <div class="image-wrap">...</div>

                <div class="title">....</div>

                <div class="description">...</div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="carousel-arrow">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <i class="arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/u21ezn9y/**

How to align .carousel-arrow elements by .image-wrap, not li height? I want the arrows will be aligned in the middle of images. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: please post your css too

Comment: You might want to consider including either a jsfiddle project, a code snippet, or the related CSS file contents.  I say this because I can see some CSS class names in your HTML markup, and that might impact how well a proposed solution would work.

Comment: That's not CSS. What's that, less, sass,...?

Comment: @JeffMahoney http://jsfiddle.net/u21ezn9y/

Comment: @j08691 sorry, converted to css: http://jsfiddle.net/u21ezn9y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also set some absolute or relative positioning ...

```
.carousel-arrow{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -2.5em;//depending on arrow
}
```

then you set `right:10px` to right  and `left:10px` to left  , this is how carousel arrows are usually set...

Comment: this is a solution for one breakpoint, but what if the height of image-wrap will be change? I mean the height and width of wrap-image is depend from size of screen. How to align in the middle of image-wrap dynamically?
Can I do it without js?

Comment: `top: 50%` is a responsive value

Answer (score 0):

Using only HTML / CSS, I'd remove the margins on your `.image-wrap` and give an absolute positioning on your descriptions. In this way, these tags won't be counted on the `li` height, centering the arrows.

```
.image-wrap {
    width: 170px;
    height: 220px;
    background: red;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
}

.description {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -70px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u21ezn9y/2/

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!